# How to write description of a test step in Katalon Studio in script mode?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, katalon-studio

How to write “description” in script mode using a variable?

For example:

> 'Verifing the headings ’ + actualtextvariable
>  
>   WebUI.verifyMatch(“text”, actualtextvariable, false)

Reference URL for the script mode: https://docs.katalon.com/katalon-studio/tutorials/create_test_case_using_script_mode.html.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do that. I guess the closest thing would be to log the description so you can see it in the console upon execution:

```
import com.kms.katalon.core.util.KeywordUtil

KeywordUtil.logInfo('Verifing the headings ’ + actualtextvariable)
```

Comment: Hi Mate,

Thanks for the reply,

I need to show description in HTML/CSV/excel report as I will send this report to developer so I should be more specific in report that's why, so console log cannot be useful for my case.